# When using SSIS to import a CSV file, how can you replace missing dates with the current UTC datetime?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am creating an SSIS package to import a CSV file into a SQL Server table.
The CSV file has a date column and the value will be missing from some of the rows.
The missing value is represented by two consecutive commas(i.e. val1,,va3).
When the value is missing, I want to insert the current date and time in UTC.

Within a Dervied Column Transformation I am using:

```
REPLACENULL(DateCreated, GetUtcDate())
```

This doesn't work; instead, the value 0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 is being inserted.

Details:
The SQL Server table is expecting the date format: **Datetime2(7)**

The flat file connection manager uses **database timestamp with precision [DT_DBTIMESTAMP2]**

How can I replace the missing values with the current UTC datetime?

Comment: Did you try setting a default value for the column?

Answer (score 0):

The column might not be NULL so the REPLACENULL isn't triggering

The default flat file source behavior is to replace empty column values with an empty string or empty date, double check on your flatfile source and ensure that your are importing empty columns as NULLs.

[image: Incoming NULL]

The REPLACENULL should then register the column as being NULL and replace it with GetUtcDate()